# How to Display Images in a particular order using OpenCV in Python?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I am writing a program that takes a string from user and displays sign language images of each character in that string. This code displays images which overlap on each other. Is there a way I can display these images in the order that they were taken an input? [This is the output I am currently getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0e38.png) [This is how I want the output to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZkif.png)

```
import cv2

print("Say something !!!")
say = input()
i=1

for x in say :
    if x == " ":
        continue
    img = cv2.imread("TrainData\\" + x + "_1.jpg")
    cv2.imshow(x + str(i), img)
    i= i+1
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I want to display images from left to right according to the input.

Comment: Can you show what you want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have attached the desired output. I just don't want the images to overlap.

Comment: It is not possible to control image window location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to position windows, you could concatenate the images side-by-side and display them in a single window:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Load the 4 letters we need
h = cv2.imread('h.png',0)
e = cv2.imread('e.png',0)
l = cv2.imread('l.png',0)
o = cv2.imread('o.png',0)

# Append images side-by-side
result = np.concatenate((h,e,l,l,o),axis=1)

# Save to disk, or display as a single, wide image
cv2.imwrite('result.png',result)
```

[image]

---

Of course, you can make a spacer shim if you want:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Load the 4 letters we need
h = cv2.imread('h.png',0)
e = cv2.imread('e.png',0)
l = cv2.imread('l.png',0)
o = cv2.imread('o.png',0)

shim = np.ones((200,10),dtype=np.uint8)*255

# Append images side-by-side
result = np.concatenate((h,shim,e,shim,l,shim,l,shim,o),axis=1)
cv2.imwrite('result.png',result)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But the thing is I will be taking input string from the user and then display images accordingly. How can I use this code to display any number of images?

Comment: Create an empty list, then use `list.append()` to add each new letter to the list. Pass the list to `np.concatenate()` as the first parameter in place of my `(h,e,l,l,o)`.

Comment: Thanks man. There one more problem, long words/sentence do not fit into the screen in one line (axis=1). Those which do not fit are not getting displayed. Is there a way to display those images ?

Comment: I would join the letters of each word side by-side (axis=1) and then join each word below each other (axis=0) and then maybe use use `cv.resize()` to make it fit on the screen.

Comment: Or you could split your screen space into a regular grid and place each letter on a new square in the grid and move on to the next square for the next letter.